# Erro ao utilizar lapis JSF Exporter

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou tentando implementar o **Lapis JSF Exporter** utilizo PrimeFaces 5.3

na versão jsf version 2.1.20 ocorre erro e o projeto não sobe...

> Abr 26, 2016 5:29:21 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   GRAVE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1] (value [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1@1e0429c3]) and a value of type [org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.StartupFacesContextImpl] (value [org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.StartupFacesContextImpl@2351d09a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

Já na versão jsf version 2.1.28 o projeto sobe e ao utilizar o **Lapis JSF Exporter** ocorre erro:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Fonte:
https://github.com/rdicroce/jsfexporter

Comment: Após verificações,
identifiquei que no meu arquivo pom.xml
estava utilizando as dependências "api e impl" do myfaces junto com o "api e impl" do JSF 
ocorre conflitos, após remover as dependências do jsf funcionou.

Comment: Se você encontrou a solução, podes responder abaixo como o fez para solucionar o problema.

Comment: certo agradeço a dica... vou responder e finalizar,após marcar como solucionado...

Comment: Alison, o SOtp não é um forum, o funcionamento aqui é diferente. O **marcar como solucionado** aqui é representado pelo `v` na resposta, que significa resposta aceita. Dê uma olhada no [tour] para ver o funcionamento do site.

Comment: sim, verifiquei o tour... ... já respondi e após 1hr vou aceitar a resposta... :) vlw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após verificações, identifiquei que no meu arquivo pom.xml estava utilizando as dependências "api e impl" do myfaces junto com o "api e impl" do JSF ocorre conflitos, após remover as dependências do jsf funcionou.

EX: do arquivo POM

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>${myfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${myfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

COMENTEI ESSA PARTE......

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.28</version>
    </dependency>
```

.................